# How to open new VSCode terminal window from command line

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, visual-studio-code, command

How do you open a new integrated terminal from the command line in VSCode

I have tried

```
open -a Terminal
```

But that opens in a MacOS terminal.

My main goal is running one npm script to automatically set up the environment. Concurrently doesn't fully work for my purposes.